# pd.to_csv date format of saved csv is different

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Input file in pandas-

[image]

```
 data.to_csv('jan_feb_warning_data3.csv', encoding='utf-8')
```

output csv has different date format. Why is it so? how to avoid it?

[image]

Comment: right click open as text ..

Comment: Have you tried to open this in notepad? - It might be just excel picking them up incorrectly. If not you can still try pd.to_datetime(df['date_col'], format = '%Y-%m-%d') to make sure - but I think it is just excel..

Comment: @Wen-Ben ,  yaah as text/notepad format is correct but I want some plots in csv/excel. Even when I copied from notepad++ ( correct format) to excel again 2 different formats have come up!!

Comment: When you open the file , make sure that columns is text type

Comment: @Wen-Ben, how to make sure as every column is text only ?( I saved as pd.to_csv)

Comment: Save it to txt, then open it as excel , then you will see the format tap, make your columns as text .and then save it as excel again . also , you can format your  columns by short date format in excel . :-)

Comment: yaah @Wen-Ben now its loaded as text and format is proper.

Comment: So the mission completed? :-)

Comment: @Wen-Ben indeed completed.